# Angular multi step form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hello im using angular 13 , building reactive forms with steps each step represents a form to fill by user with the same submit logic for each form , on last step i want all the data stored in each variable(that containing relative step data) and merge it into one big object to send to backend in order to create user / edit, any suggestion how should i do that?  .. Code down below

```
  ngOnInit(): void { 
this.options2 = {
  theme: 'classic',
  width: "300"
}
this.landingService.getAllSapaksList()  // observable send api request set array data and remove duplicated values
.subscribe((res:any) => {
  this.biz_listAPI = res.data;
  this.biz_listAPI = [...new Set(this.biz_listAPI)];
});
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-wrap');
while (elements.length > 0){
  elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
const token = this._is.get_index_id();
  this.userPhone = Object.values(token)[0];
   
this.landingService.checkIfDataExist(this.userPhone)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.exists) {
        this.router.navigate(['index']);
      }
    }, err => console.log(err))
this.createIndexFormStep0 = new FormGroup({
  logo: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
  cover: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
  title: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
  ownerName: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
  ownerImage: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]),
  description: new FormControl('' , [Validators.required]), 
});

this.createIndexFormStep1 = new FormGroup({
    mini_title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    free_description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    gallery_photos: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});

this.createIndexFormStep2 = new FormGroup({
  phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required ,Validators.pattern(this._sds.onlyNumberRegEx)]),
  fax: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this._sds.onlyNumberRegEx)]),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this._sds.emailRegEx)]),
  youtube: new FormControl(''),
  facebook: new FormControl(''),
  instagram: new FormControl(''),
});

this.createIndexFormStep3 = new FormGroup({
  biz_photo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  biz_name: new FormControl([], [Validators.required]),
  biz_description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  discount: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this._sds.onlyNumberRegEx)])
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to deal with these kinds of tasks is to consolidate all of the `FormGroup`s into one `FormGroup`, then iterate over its' keys on submit.

**Step 1**: Add `form: FormGroup` to your component

**Step 2**: Instead of having each group on its' own, create them (preferebly, with `FormBuilder`) within the main group, i.e.:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      createIndexFormStep0: this.formBuilder.group({
            logo: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
            /*...*/,
      });
      createIndexFormStep1: /*...*/,
      createIndexFormStep2: /*...*/,
      createIndexFormStep3: /*...*/,
});
```

**Step 3**: Update the template correspondingly

**Step 4**: Use `Object.keys` to build the request object:

```
let request = {};
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(groupKey => {
    const group = (this.form.get(groupKey) as FormGroup);
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(controlKey => {
        request[controlKey] = this.form.get([groupKey, controlKey]).value;
    });
});
```